# choco install or choco upgrade with different install arguments without re-downloading

Tags: chocolatey

`choco upgrade --force -y --installarguments "/quiet REMOVE=DS" calibre` removes the desktop shortcut for Calibre, but this command re-downloads the whole package to do so.

Without `--force` it doesn't work.

Is there a way to use the already existing `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\calibre\calibre.nupkg` and not re-download the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction that you are giving to Chocolatey is to expressly re-run the entire command again, which will result in it re-downloading the package.

As a workaround, you could do the following:

1. Copy the calibre.nupkg from the `C:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/calibre` folder to another location, for example `C:/temp`
2. Use the following command `choco upgrade --force -y --installarguments "/quiet REMOVE=DS" calibre --source C:\temp`

This will use the local package (the nupkg) rather than downloading it again from the Community Repository.

Comment: Since `choco upgrade --force -y --installarguments "/quiet REMOVE=DS" calibre --source %PROGRAMDATA%\chocolatey\lib\calibre` doesn't work Chocolatey doesn't support what I want, but copying is a good workaround, thanks!

Comment: One of the first things that Chocolatey does as part of the upgrade, is to move all the files from the `lib/calibre` folder to a `lib-bkp/calibre` folder.  As a result, no, that command will not work, and you would have to first move the nupkg to another location.